# Contact form plugin ajax submit URL not working

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php, ajax, plugin-contactform

I am using contact form plugin for forms in my craft website. For avoiding page redirection, I followed ajax submit for the form, but it is not redirected to controller code.

**My form is as below:-**

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="basic-form" id="contactForm">
       {{ csrfInput() }}
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact-form/send">
       <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="text-field" id="text-630573652" name="firstName" value="" required="" placeholder="Name *" autocomplete="off">
       </div>
      <div class="layout-sm-12">
             <button type="submit" class="btn white-btn-outline submit-btn">LET'S TALK<i class="icon-long-arrow-bold-right"></i></button>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

**My ajax script is as follows:-**

```
$(function () {
        $('#contactForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/',
            data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                 alert(response);
            }
        });

        });
});
```

For this I am getting error in console like 404 page not found. How to redirect to send controller index function using ajax request. As per other tutorials '/' is not working here.

Anyone please help...

Comment: If you read the docs: The only required fields are fromEmail and message. Everything else is optional. You have neither.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am asking for how we will redirect to controller url using ajax

Comment: Since you have **contact-form/send** as your hidden field for form action, have you tried using this for the AJAX url?

Comment: Thank you. That works.